# Which Oracle 11g has DBCA?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dbca

I am having an issue with Oracle 11g. I need to download an Oracle 11g database that has the Database Configuration Assistant. I had already downloaded Oracle 11g Express Edition not realizing it apparently doesn't have DBCA.

So which Oracle 11g do I need to download so I can use DBCA?

I am on the Oracle website and see Oracle 11g Release 2. I have a Windows laptop with Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be *any other version* (Standard or Enterprise).

11gXE has its limitations and creates a sample database during the installation process. As it allows only one instance, DBCA is useless in that version and is, therefore, not shipped with it.

Answer (score 0):

Standard or Enterprise edition of Oracle 11g would do.
I have downloaded the version from Oracle and DBCA worked for me.